# synchronized block not executing in servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, synchronized

I am trying to study and learn about Java Servlets.  I have this example that I am using, but for some reason the page stops loading when it hits the synchronized block.

```
package org.recipe.ch01;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "CurrentDateAndTime", urlPatterns = {"/CurrentDateAndTime"})
public class CurrentDateAndTime extends HttpServlet
{
Date currDateAndTime;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
    {
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet CurrentDateAndTime</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet CurrentDateAndTime at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("<br/>");
        synchronized (currDateAndTime)
        {
            currDateAndTime = new Date();
            out.println("The current date and time is: " + currDateAndTime);
        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void  doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    processRequest(request, response);
}
}
```

The webpage will load everything up to line 29.
I am using GlassFish 4.1.1

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: `currDateAndTime` is `null`. `synchronized` statements throw NPE on `null`. Look at your logs.

Comment: Why would `currDateAndTime` even need to be an instance field?

Comment: That was it!  It was the example, there is no reason for it to be.  I think they were just trying to show how synchronized worked, and that all servlets are threaded.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is correct. However I am curious why you would even use a synchronized block in this case. I would just delete the block. I would also make currDateAndTime a local variable rather than a class member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the comments, this code is nonsensical and there's no point to making the current datetime an instance member.

Before entering a synchronized block, the expression in the parens following the synchronized keyword has to be evaluated in order to figure out what lock needs to be acquired. This evaluation is performed each time a thread tries to enter the block. If the expression evaluates to null (which it does here because the instance variable hasn't been initialized) then a NullPointerException gets thrown.

Changing the value of a variable whose contents threads are locking on is a very bad idea. When the thread executing the block changes the value of the variable, the expression evaluated by other threads trying to acquire the lock resolves to a different object than the one currently held by the first thread, making the lock held by the first thread irrelevant and allowing a second thread to acquire the new object's lock and proceed even if the first thread is not done, with potentially disastrous consequences if there was anything important going on in the synchronized block (unlike the posted example). Even once you get this to work by making sure the variable is not null, it's a good pattern to avoid.